# Help with regex pulling XML data from response body in PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex, parsing

I am working on a project that pulls data from JMS queue using PHP and Zend Framework.  The HTTP client response is below.  All I need is the XML string.

I came up with /(.*)</RequestDetails>/gs which tests ok on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but the preg_match call is returning an empty matches array.

I'm going to continue to hunt around for a pattern, but thought I would post here as well.

Thanks to all who read, etc...

Steve

UPDATE: I can't get the code to paste correctly.  Here's a link to a pastbin: http://pastebin.com/rQxzcfSg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet:

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOT

blah blah <0>
<RequestDetails><1><2><3>test</RequestDetails>
<RequestDetails><4><5><6>blah
more blah blah
</RequestDetails>
blah blah <7>


EOT;

print $text;

preg_match_all('/<RequestDetails>(.*?)<\/RequestDetails>/s', $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Generates this output:

```
blah blah <0>
<RequestDetails><1><2><3>test</RequestDetails>
<RequestDetails><4><5><6>blah
more blah blah
</RequestDetails>
blah blah <7>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <RequestDetails><1><2><3>test</RequestDetails>
            [1] => <RequestDetails><4><5><6>blah
more blah blah
</RequestDetails>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <1><2><3>test
            [1] => <4><5><6>blah
more blah blah

        )

)
```

I've used `preg_match_all` instead of `/g` flag, and also used `(.*?)` reluctant matching, which is really what you want to get multiple matches.

To see why it makes a difference, in the following text, there are two `A.*?Z` matches, but only one `A.*Z`.

```
 ---A--Z---A--Z----
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
       A.*Z
```

That said, parsing XML using regex is ill-advised. Use a proper XML parser; it'll make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, why bother with complex Regexes when PHP 5 comes with on-board tools like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php)?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 

print_r($xml); // should output complete tree for you to walk through easily
```

You'd just have to remove the MIME parts and submit only the raw XML to the function, of course.

More on [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) here.

Comment: Agree, but the problem is that the HTTP response includes more data than just the XML that I need.  I need to pull the XML out of the response and then load the string into SimpleXML

Comment: @spdaly okay. As long as the XML is clearly defined, a regex may be the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `g` is invalid. Use `m` instead (for multiline). Test `/(.*)<\/RequestDetails>/gs` and `/(.*)<\/RequestDetails>/ms` using [this tester](http://www.switchplane.com/utilities/preg_match-regular-expression-tester.php).